# Audio Toolbox sound change problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, audiotoolbox

i'm new in iphone programin and i wrote a little animation program. i used audiotoolbox frame for sound and it was working.
But when i change the sound file. (deleted exfile from resources and folder and add the other file with the same name, same path)

but after changing sound is not working.

i also rechanged sound file with ex-file.But even ex file is not working.

(both are  .wav type)
if you want i can write codes here.

thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rewriting the code?
You could also try using the AVFoundation Framework instead.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AudioPlayerViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog([error description]);
    else
        [audioPlayer play];

}
```